# Calculating the percentage of dates (SQL Server)

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, sql-server-2012, percentage

I'm trying to add an auto-calculated field in SQL Server 2012 Express, that stores the % of project completion, by calculating the date difference by using:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.projects
ADD PercentageCompleted AS (select COUNT(*)  FROM projects WHERE project_finish > project_start) * 100 / COUNT(*)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Msg 1046, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it would be possible (it isn't), it is anyway not something you would want to have as a caculated column:

1. it will be the same value in each row
2. the entire table would need to be updated after every insert/update

You should consider doing this in a `stored procedure` or a user `defined function` instead.Or even better in the business logic of your application,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. You could write a trigger to figure it out or do it as part of an update statement.

Comment: Can you get an SQLDataSource to calculate it though by using some function, instead of creating another column?

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing "percentageCompleted" as a duplicated column value in the same table as your project data?

If this is the case, I would not recommend this, because it would duplicate the data.

If you don't care about duplicate data, try something separating the steps out like this:

`ALTER TABLE dbo.projects
ADD PercentageCompleted decimal(2,2)` --You could also store it as a varchar or char

`declare @percentageVariable decimal(2,2)`

`select @percentageVariable = (select count(*) from projects where Project_finish > project_start) / (select count(*) from projects)` -- need to get ratio by completed/total

```
update projects
set PercentageCompleted = @percentageVariable
```

this will give you a decimal value in that table, then you can format it on select if you desire to % + PercentageCompleted * 100